# Bundling node module before distribution

Tags: node.js, bundling-and-minification, node-modules

I have a node module which is intended to be installed as a global module and meant to be executed in a command line. Since it's a command line tool, I want the install experience to be fast.

Rather than installing the dependencies, what If I bundle and provide a single file and have no dependencies to install. What are the pros and cons of this approach and what are the recommended tools to do such bundling?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just want the installer to bundle the complete set of node_modules. I don't see why you can't just let the user install them using a simple [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) install.

We, the developers will have some huge advantages as..

- we can decide which version of the module to use in the package.json
- we also have a an option to use the latest and greatest version(Security concerns can be addressed fast)
- If you are willing to publish that to npm , just having a package.json is much better than having all bundled up

after all node is about packaging and modularization,

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: My main concern is the installation time. As I add more and more dependencies, the initial install time of the module increases. I want a way to reduce this.

Comment: Strictly speaking, [tag:npm] is about packaging and node.js deals with modularization.